# Cauchys integral formula with an exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

The question is to evaluate the integral :
$$
\oint\limits_{|z-1|=2}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2(z^2-4)e^z}
$$
by using Cauchy's integral formula.

I have this so far:

We have a circle with radius 2 centered at 1, and we have 3 singularities, $z=2, z=-2, z=0$. However, $z=-2$ is not included within our circle, so we don't need to worry about it.

Now we can rewrite what we have as
$$
\oint\limits_{|z-1|=2}\frac{dz}{z^2(z^2-4)e^z} = \oint\limits_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{\frac{e^{-z}}{z^2-4}}{z^2} \mathrm{d}z+ 
\oint\limits_{|z-2|=\epsilon}\frac{\frac{e^{-z}}{z^2(z+2)}}{z-2} \mathrm{d}z.
$$
My solution ends up as $\frac{i\pi}{2} $+ $\frac{i\pi}{8e^2}$.
I think this is correct, but when I do my calculations I end up with the wrong solution (the solution is in the back of the book). Can anyone guide me in the right direction, or tell me if what I'm doing is wrong? The answer given in the back of the book is given as $\frac{-i\pi}{2} +\frac{i\pi}{4e^2}.$

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm using Gamelins complex analysis book, and this is from the section on Cauchy's integral formula, and residue theorem doesn't show up for a couple more chapters or so.

Comment: You're not showing your solution, but $-\pi i/2 + \pi i/(4 e^2)$ is not the correct answer.

Comment: I changed it and my final solution is in there now

Comment: $\pi i/2 + \pi i/(8 e^2)$ is correct (with the usual assumption that $|z - 1| = 2$ is oriented counterclockwise).

Comment: Oh sweet okay, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pole $\;z=0\;$ has multiplicity $\;2,\;$ so
$$2\pi i\underset0{\text{ Res }}\dfrac{e^{-z}}{z^2(z^2-4)} = 2\pi i\, \lim\limits_{z\to0}\left(\dfrac{e^{-z}}{z^2-4}\right)' = \lim\limits_{z\to 0}\,e^{-z} \left(\dfrac1{4-z}-\dfrac{2z}{(z^2-4)^2}\right)\\
 = 2\pi i\cdot \dfrac14 = i\,\frac\pi2,$$
and this method applies quite correct way to get $\;c_{-1}\;$ from the [Laurent series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E-z%20%2F%28z%5E4-4z%5E2%29%20near%200) in the form of
$$-\frac1{4 z^2} + \frac1{4 z} - \frac3{16} + \frac5{48}z+\dots$$

At the same time, the pole $\;z=2\;$ is a simple one, and
$$2\pi i \underset{2}{\text{ Res }}\,\dfrac{e^{-z}}{z^2(z^2-4)} = 2\pi i\,\lim\limits_{z\to 2}\dfrac{e^{-z}}{z^2(z+2)} = \dfrac{2\pi i}{16e^2},$$
wherein the [Laurent series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E-z%20%2F%28z%5E4-4z%5E2%29%20near%202) also corresponds to the obtained result.